# How do I determine count of unique levels by categories

Tags: r, aggregate, unique

I am analyzing a set of data that includes multiple, repeated IDs and years. I am trying to count unique IDs by year. I can count unique IDs for all years using unique(). I tried using table() and aggregate() with unique() and length(), but got "unique() applies only to vectors" error. I wrote a "for" loop that works but there must be an easier way to do this.

Here is an example code for the "for" loop:

```
years <- as.factor( c( rep("2001",3), rep("2002", 5), rep( "2003", 4)))
id <- as.factor( rep(1:6,2))
mydata <- data.frame( years, id )
attach( mydata )

levels.year <- levels( years)
id.by.year <- data.frame( Year = 1:3, Counts = rep(NA, 3) )
for ( i in 1:3 ){
  id.by.year[i,1] <- levels.year[i]
  mydata.by.year <- mydata[ years == levels.year[i],]
  id.by.year[i,2] <- length( unique( mydata.by.year$id))
}
id.by.year
```

Output looks like this:

```
  Year Counts
1 2001      3
2 2002      5
3 2003      4
```

Comment: You want a simple frequency table? Try: table(years)

Comment: You should use `data.frame(.)` to create a data.frame directly. Don't use `cbind` and then convert it to a `data.frame`. Because `cbind` converts it into a matrix where all column *have* to be the same type!

Comment: Thanks, Arun. I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `aggregate`

```
years <- as.factor( c( rep("2001",3), rep("2002", 5), rep( "2003", 4)))
id <- as.factor( rep(1:6,2))
mydata <- data.frame( id, years ) # do not use `cbind`

aggregate(id~years, FUN=length, data=mydata)
##  years id
##1  2001  3
##2  2002  5
##3  2003  4
```

Comment: Thanks Jilber. I know now where I made a mistake while using aggregate(). I used FUN = length(unique(). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use table with both dimensions and then rowSums on the result of a logical `> 0` operation:

```
rowSums( with(mydata, table( years, id) ) > 0  )
2001 2002 2003 
   3    5    4
```

Jus adding this so you can see the intermediate structure:

```
>  with(mydata, table( years, id) )
      id
years  1 2 3 4 5 6
  2001 1 1 1 0 0 0
  2002 1 1 0 1 1 1
  2003 0 0 1 1 1 1
```